# Produce output from empty window

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Is it possible to produce output from a stream analytics query, using the "group by window" expression, when the window is empty?

For instance, in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-get-started/) example, the query:

`SELECT System.Timestamp as WindowEnd, SwitchNum, COUNT(*) as CallCount
FROM CallStream TIMESTAMP BY CallRecTime
GROUP BY TUMBLINGWINDOW(s, 5), SwitchNum`

produces the output:

- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z UK      1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z US      1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z China   1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z Germany 1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z UK      3
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z US      1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:50.000Z Australia   2
- ...

Is it possible to make it produce something like:

- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z China   0
- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z Germany 0
- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z UK      1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z US      1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:40.000Z Australia   0
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z China   1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z Germany 1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z UK      3
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z US      1
- 2015-04-15T22:10:45.000Z Australia   0
- ...

?

The objective is to detect, using a hopping window, if there were no events in the last x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN with a lookup table of SwitchNum values, which will produce a result with NULL if no values are in the window.

This blog post explains in more detail: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/streamanalytics/archive/2014/12/09/how-to-query-for-all-events-and-no-event-scenarios.aspx

Comment: That looks like it would work, however, the reference data would have to be on the left side, which apparently is not allowed in stream analytics.

Comment: @pfouto This blog describes how to (sort of) put reference data on the left side of a join: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2015/12/17/how-to-find-absence-of-signal-in-a-stream-analytics-job.aspx

Comment: Dead links :-( Can anyone find an alternative?